# Ubuntu Live USB installation found corrupted file, yet disk md5 checks out

Tags: system-installation, md5sum, data-corruption

An attempt was made to install ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64 on macbook pro-11,2 using a bootable USB flash drive, following the directions given [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx). Before the installation, I checked the disk for defects, result shows error being found in 1 file.

To identify the source of error, I followed the following procedures.

1) verify md5 digest of the downloaded .iso file, which is correct. (cab6dd5ee6d649ed1b24e807c877c0ae)

2) generate md5 digest for the .dmg file created by the command

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.dmg ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso
```

(bab7428eabad4eea871f606d54af51f8)

3) generate md5 digest for the usb flash drive created using the .dmg image.

(bab7428eabad4eea871f606d54af51f8)

Procedure 1) indicates the downloaded file is correct; 3) results in the same md5 digest as 2) indicates that the flash drive has no data error. However, it is unclear whether the conversion from .iso to .dmg affects data integrity.

My question is, how do I know whether the .dmg is valid. And what could go wrong during the .iso->.dmg conversion process? Or is there a bug in the ubuntu defect checking program?

Comment: ***[Do Not Cross Post!](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244191/ubuntu-live-usb-installation-found-corrupted-file-yet-disk-md5-checks-out)*** Pick *one site* for support, and have patience.

Comment: The other post deleted, sorry, won't do that again.

Comment: What file was corrupted?  How is it different than the one in the ISO image?

Comment: @casey  what should I do to find out which file? The ubuntu disk check program does not show which file is corrupted.

Comment: @314314314 from your question is sounded like you already "found 1 file" that was corrupted.  If you were referring to the DMG file itself, then I misunderstood.